# video encoder for a picture + voice (supported by mobile phones)

Tags: android, iphone, audio, video

I wonder what is the best option to store a single picture and short voice memo in one file? That needs to be openable by mobile phones in browser (iOS, Android) and preferably be shown as a single full screen photo and sound playing in background.

Effectively i'm looking for a most size efficient combination of something like MP3 + JPG. 
If i do it in a single .mov i guess i loose a lot of space due to compression of each and the same frame 24 frames/second.

A rough list of options which comes to mind:

- .mov
- Mpeg4
- H.264
- QuickTime
- HTML5 video format (Theora?)
- store it in Flash (but this is not supported by iOS)

EDIT1:

tried storing h.264 in .mp4 container, files are small enough (around 1Mb), but somehow it does not work on an Android phone of my friend. Probably i need more testing, but it seems Android OS does not like proprietary codecs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My most intuitive solution for this would be to store a JPEG and an MP3 separately on the server. To download one entity as a single unit, download a bit of JSON or XML data that contains pointers to the picture and the audio file.

If you are set on having one file do the job, you might try embedding the JPEG inside the ID3 metadata of an MP3 file (this type of metadata functionality exists to, e.g., store album art with a music file). You would want to make sure that the ID3 tag is near the start of the file. JavaScript within the mobile browser could fetch the file, a third party library could do the ID3 parsing (some Googling reveals that such libraries exist; don't know if they all support fetching a JPEG image). Then the JS would need to be able to feed the file into an audio tag for playback, which I'm not sure is possible.

Another thing to experiment with is a .MP4 which encodes the audio track along with a single video frame with a really, *reeeaaallly* long duration. You would have to experiment to determine if the mobile browsers handle that gracefully while also allowing smooth audio seeking. If they don't, then perhaps re-encode the frame with every 1-5 seconds to keep the bitrate minimal.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Talking about .mp4 you mean container or codec?

Comment: MP4 container with either H.264 video or possibly just JPEG.